# Calculating angles between two points in 3d space

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine, euler-angles

I have two points (cube game object) in **Unity**, P1(x,y,z) and P2(x,y,z) and I have to set the **MainCamera** position and rotation along the vector between P2P1.

I tried different methods but was not successful.
All suggestions are welcomed.
Thanks.

Comment: Please be more specific: what do you mean by "set the MainCamera position and rotation along the vector between P2P1"? Is that the direction? Are there any requirement concerning the roll of the camera?

Comment: research "camera lookat()"

Comment: Two points do not span an angle. Are you referring to the angle formed by P1, the origin, and P2?

Comment: @njuffa _"Two points do not span an angle"_ - well no.  A _logical_ 3D _"point"_ in Unity is a physical `Vector3` (there is no Point3 type) and Unity defines [Vector3.Dot()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Dot.html) for calculating the cosine between them.  The OP's **P1** is essentially a vector from (0,0,0) to _"(x,y,z)"_

Comment: @MickyD Camera lookat() was very good point. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

We can find angle between 2 vectors according the dot production.
angle = arccos ( a * b / |a| * |b| );
where: 
a * b = ax * bx + ay * by + az * bz
|a| = sqrt( ax * ax + ay * ay + az * az )
|b| = sqrt( bx * bx + by * by + bz * bz )
Or just use this method: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Angle.html